# Python Write To File Missing Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble using python to write strings into a file:
(what I'm trying to do is using python to generate some C programs)
The code I have is the following:

```
filename = "test.txt"
i = 0
string = "image"
tempstr = ""
average1 = "average"
average2 = "average*average"
output = ""
FILE = open(filename,"w")
while i < 20:
    j = 0
    output = "square_sum = square_sum + "
    while j < 20:        
        tempstr = string + "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j)        
        output = output + tempstr + "*" + tempstr + " + " + average2 + " - 2*" + average1 + "*" + tempstr        
        if j != 19:        
            output = output + " + "
        if j == 19:
            output = output + ";"        
        j = j + 1
    output = output + "\n"
    i = i + 1
    print(output)
    FILE.writelines(output)    
FILE.close
```

The print gives me correct output, but the FILE has last line missing and some of the second last line missing. What's the problem in writing strings into file?

Thank you!

Comment: try using `with` statements... You won't have these silly errors.

Comment: Doing `while i < 20` and keeping track of the counter yourself is generally unnecessary in Python - do `for i in range(20):` for the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably help if you called the method...

```
FILE.close()
```

Comment: also noting that the reason you need a FILE.close() is because you must flush the unwritten data buffer. .write[lines]() doesn't actually write to a file, it writes to a file buffer that must get flushed to the disk (flushing happens either when the buffer is full, or when you close the file). you may also call .flush() directly, though it is probably better to have it be automatic (flushing too often will hurt performance).

Comment: Thank for help, but I want to know why this problem will happen without calling this method?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't calling the `close()` method, just mentioning it in the last line.  You need parens to invoke a function.

Python's `with` statement can make that unnecessary though:

```
with open(filename,"w") as the_file:
    while i < 20:
        j = 0
        output = "square_sum = square_sum + "
        ...
        print(output)
        the_file.writelines(output)
```

When the `with` clause is exited, `the_file` will be closed automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
with open(filename,"w") as FILE:
    while i < 20:
        # rest of your code with proper indent...
```

no close needed...

Answer (score 1):

First, a Pythonified version of your code:

```
img = 'image_{i}_{j}'
avg = 'average'
clause = '{img}*{img} + {avg}*{avg} - 2*{avg}*{img}'.format(img=img, avg=avg)
clauses = (clause.format(i=i, j=j) for i in xrange(20) for j in xrange(20))
joinstr = '\n    + '
output = 'square_sum = {};'.format(joinstr.join(clauses))

fname = 'output.c'
with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
    print output
    outf.write(output)
```

Second, it looks like you are hoping to speed up your C code by fanatical inlining. I very much doubt the speed gains will justify your efforts over something like

```
maxi = 20;
maxj = 20;
sum = 0;
sqsum = 0;
for(i=0; i<maxi; i++)
    for(j=0; j<maxj; j++) {
        t = image[i][j];
        sum += t;
        sqsum += t*t;
    }

square_sum = sqsum + maxi*maxj*average*average - 2*sum*average;
```

Comment: I'm not speeding up my C code. I'm using a very specialized C compiler that the syntax I can use is very limited (no variable in array index, no function call, no pointer..) That's why I need to write some code "manually". But still thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your indentation may be incorrect, but just some other comments about your code:

`writelines()` writes the content of a list or iterator to the file.
Since your outputting a single string, just use `write()`.

```
lines ["lineone\n", "line two\n"]
f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

Or just:

```
output = "big long string\nOf something important\n"
f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

As another side note it maybe helpful to use the `+=` operator.

```
output += "more text"
# is equivalent to
output = output + "more text"
```